# Calling a function from an explicit cursor

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to call the stored function findtotalcarmodels from this PL/SQL block.  The way this code is written is not the way I would do it in production, however it is an exercise in 'lateral' thinking.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAP SIZE 12000 
Declare 
v_model VARCHAR2(40);
v_cost NUMBER;
v_reg VARCHAR2(10);
v_carcategory VARCHAR2(40);
v_totalcars NUMBER;
v_count DATE;
v_maxcount DATE;
v_maxdept VARCHAR2(20);
cursor carcur IS 
SELECT * FROM i_car;
v_car carcur%ROWTYPE;
Cursor c_date (p_reg i_booking.registration%TYPE) IS
SELECT date_reserved
FROM i_booking
WHERE registration = p_reg;
v_date c_date%ROWTYPE;
Begin 
v_totalcars := findtotalcarmodels();
FOR v_car IN carcur LOOP
If v_cost <=50000 THEN v_carcategory := 'Budget Car';
End IF;
If v_cost BETWEEN 50000 AND 100000 THEN v_carcategory := 'Standard Car';
End IF;
If v_cost >100000 THEN v_carcategory := 'Premium Car';
End If;
FOR v_date IN c_date(v_car.registration) LOOP
v_count := v_count + 1;
END LOOP;
IF v_count > v_maxcount THEN
v_maxcount := v_count;
v_maxdept := v_car.registration;
END IF;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Registration:'|| ' '|| v_car.registration); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cost:'|| '$' ||v_car.Cost); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Model Name:'|| ' '||v_car.model_name); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Car Category:'|| ' '||v_carcategory);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total number of Cars:'|| ' '||v_totalcars);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Most Recent Rental Date: '|| ' '||v_maxcount);
DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE; 
END LOOP; 
END;
```

I am getting the error:

```
v_totalcars := findtotalcarmodels();
               *
ERROR at line 19: 
ORA-06550: line 19, column 16: 
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FINDTOTALCARMODELS' 
ORA-06550: line 19, column 1: 
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Am I calling my function correctly in the right position?

This is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function findtotalcarmodels
(model_name_in IN varchar2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
counter INTEGER := 0;
CURSOR car_count_cur IS
SELECT model_name FROM i_car WHERE model_name = model_name_in;
Rec_car_details car_count_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN car_count_cur;
LOOP
FETCH car_count_cur INTO Rec_car_details;
EXIT WHEN car_count_cur%NOTFOUND;
counter := counter + 1;
END LOOP;
CLOSE car_count_cur;
RETURN counter;
END;
```

Comment: You're not passing the function the correct number of arguments as indicated in the error message. Look at the function and work out what data you need to give it in order to work and then do that.

Comment: Hi Ben.  I have included my function.  I am new to PL/SQL so I am not sure what you mean by passing arguments?

Comment: You are evidently not running the same code you have posted.  Line 19 is the call to `findtotalcarmodels`.  In your error message you are clearly not passing it the model name it asks for, but in your code, you are passing it `model_name`.  Besides, I can't see where `model_name` comes from.

Comment: Model_name comes from the table i_car.  The function is counting the amount of cars belonging to each model name and returning a number.  I need the PL/SQL block to display the total amount of cars for each model.  The output should look like similar to this, but with actual values and multiple times:                                                  Registration: H266MHU 
Cost:$63000 
Model Name: ASTON V8 
Car Category: 
Total number of Cars: 0 
Most Recent Rental Date:

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have no idea why you're getting that error with that function. The error indicates that you're not giving the function the correct number of arguments. Judging by the function that's clearly not what's happening, or it's not the same function.

---

You've just changed the function call; the function requires an argument so the "incorrect" code you had in your first revision was actually correct.

---

However, let's put that to one side for a second and look again at what you're doing.

1. Your function is a count on a table. There's no need for a cursor or looping, incrementing variables or anything. You can simplify it to

   ```
   select count(*) from i_car where model_name = :model_name
   ```
2. You never assign the variables `v_count` or `v_maxcount` a value so incrementing them will still result in a NULL. They're dates anyway, so it's a little strange to be incrementing them.
3. Your cursor `c_date` is just another count; once again no need for a loop.
4. The `model_name` variable is never initialised so your function will not return a result.

There are a lot of ways to simplify this; though I'm going to guess a few things here. Change your `carcur` cursor to the following:

```
select i.*
     , case cost
            when <= 50000 then 'Budget Car'
            when <= 100000 then 'Standard Car'
            else 'Premium Car'
       end as category
    , count(*) over ( partition by model_name ) as total_cars
 from i_cars
```

This appears to enable you to remove your IF statements and your function. You can then remove your second loop by performing an outer join on `i_booking` (you need to add the primary key in yourself):

```
select i.*
     , case c.cost
            when <= 50000 then 'Budget Car'
            when <= 100000 then 'Standard Car'
            else 'Premium Car'
       end as category
    , count(distinct c.primary_key) 
         over ( partition by c.model_name ) as total_cars
    , count(b.date_reserved) 
         over ( partition by b.registration ) as reserved_ct
 from i_cars c
 left outer join i_booking b
   on c.registration = b.registration
```

I'm not 100% certain on the max stuff as it's not clear at all where it's assigned (it's not) but it looks as though you might be wanting to find the maximum count by model etc, in which case you can use a sub-query on the above cursor:

```
select sub.*
     , max(total_cars) over () as max_cars
     , max(reserved_ct) over () as max_reserved
  from ( select i.*
              , case c.cost
                     when <= 50000 then 'Budget Car'
                     when <= 100000 then 'Standard Car'
                     else 'Premium Car'
                end as category
             , count(distinct c.primary_key) 
                 over ( partition by c.model_name ) as total_cars
             , count(b.date_reserved) 
                 over ( partition by b.registration ) as reserved_ct
          from i_cars c
          left outer join i_booking b
            on c.registration = b.registration
               ) sub
```

If you then *need* to output it (there's rarely a need) you can loop through this single SQL statement, which gives you everything in one go:

```
declare

  c_cursor is
    select sub.*
         , max(total_cars) over () as max_cars
         , max(reserved_ct) over () as max_reserved
      from ( select i.*
                  , case c.cost
                         when <= 50000 then 'Budget Car'
                         when <= 100000 then 'Standard Car'
                         else 'Premium Car'
                    end as category
                 , count(distinct c.primary_key) 
                     over ( partition by c.model_name ) as total_cars
                 , count(b.date_reserved) 
                     over ( partition by b.registration ) as reserved_ct
              from i_cars c
              left outer join i_booking b
                on c.registration = b.registration
                   ) sub

            ;

begin

   for i in c_cursor loop
      dbms_output.put_line(i.registration);
      dbms_output.put_line(i.cost);
      ...
   end loop;

end;
```

I've reduced a PL/SQL block and a function to a single SQL statement; it may not be spot on because there's so many unknowns but it's worth trying for yourself. Simple is almost always better.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I appreciate the reply, however I need to keep the function etc.  All I need to know is how to call it from the given PL/SQL block.

Comment: What you originally posted is how to call the function @Splunk; you need to pass in the model name, which means you need to initialise it somehow... however none of the rest of your code is going to work the way you expect (if at all) and there really is no need for the function at all...

Comment: Yeah I understand what you mean.  Currently the If statements aren't working, nor is the cursor c_date which is supposed to pull in the max date reserved without using the MAX function.  The rest is OK though.